# ¿Por qué mi app se cierra apenas inicia?

Tags: android, kotlin

¿Por qué mi app falla desde que inicia? Estoy tratando de capturar gestos comunes con la clase GestureDetector de android
aquí dejo el código y la salida del logcat:

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.commongestures

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.ebookfrenzy.commongestures.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import android.view.GestureDetector
import android.view.MotionEvent
import androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import android.util.Log



abstract class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

 var gDetector: GestureDetectorCompat? = null
private val TAG = "error"
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     Log.i(TAG, "onCreate 1")
     binding = ActivityMainBindin.inflate(layoutInflater)
     Log.i(TAG, "onCreate 2")
     setContentView(binding.root)
     Log.i(TAG, "onCreate 3")
     val mySnackbar = Snackbar.make(binding.root, "hola", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
     mySnackbar.show()
     Log.i(TAG, "onCreate 4")

     this.gDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(this, this)
      gDetector?.setOnDoubleTapListener(this)


 }

 override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
     this.gDetector?.onTouchEvent(event)
     // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
     return super.onTouchEvent(event)
 }

override fun onDown(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onDown"
    return true
}

override fun onFling(event1: MotionEvent?, event2: MotionEvent,
                     velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
    binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onFling"
    return true
}


override fun onLongPress(event: MotionEvent) {
    binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onLongPress"
}

 override fun onScroll(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent, distanceX: Float,        
 distanceY: Float): Boolean {
    binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onScroll"
    return true
}

override fun onShowPress(event: MotionEvent) {
    binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onShowPress"
}
override fun onSingleTapUp(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onSingleTapUp"
    return true
}
override fun onDoubleTap(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onDoubleTap"
    return true
}
override fun onDoubleTapEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onDoubleTapEvent"
    return true
}
override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onSingleTapConfirmed"
    return true
}


}
```

Aquí la salida del logcat, tengo entendido que muestra el error, pero es muy larga y se me hace imposible determinar exactamente dónde está el error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ebookfrenzy.commongestures, PID: 11327
 java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ebookfrenzy.commongestures/com.ebookfrenzy.commongestures.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.ebookfrenzy.commongestures.MainActivity> cannot be instantiated
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)


Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.ebookfrenzy.commongestures.MainActivity> cannot be instantiated
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el LogCat se indica la causa del problema:

> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
> java.lang.Class<com.ebookfrenzy.commongestures.MainActivity> cannot be
> instantiated at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)

La clase `MainAcitivity` no puede ser instanciada, esto es debido a que la definiste como `abstract`, esto es incorrecto, nunca debes definir tu Activity como `abstract`, puedes [revisar los ejemplos de la documentación.](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-first-app?hl=es-419#4)

Define tu clase `MainActivity` de esta forma:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
...
...
```

Comment: muchas gracias ese mismo era el problema

Comment: @Delphi me quedé con la duda, por qué lo definiste la Activity como abstract ?

Answer (score 1):

Está claro que ocurre algún error en la creación del `Activity`. Creo que el problema es que marcaste la clase como abstracta. En Kotlin [las clases abstractas no pueden ser instanciadas](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#abstract-classes-declarations).

Comment: muchas gracias, eso resuelve el problema